# How to make a bone extremity automaticly reach another bone extremity

Tags: armature, bones

I'm looking for an automated way to make the edge of a bone going at the location of the edge of the bone connected to it.

[image]

I can do it manually but it's a process I have to repeat a lot. I want to move only one edge of one bone to the other, in *Edit Mode*.

Comment: So some people loose time to edit a question only for good looking effect rather than replying to a problem? Peoples here have problem in the brain,you guys have a serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, can't see anything from your pic.  Zoom out a bit, don't use sticks to draw, can't see what's what with them.

You probably want a stretch-to constraint:

[image]

Comment: You don't need a zoom out ,what you need to look is the bone edges,not the mesh